# Extracting data from a list of vector in the while loop in r

Tags: r, list, loops, while-loop

I post my follow up question about my previous one. From this code, I want a list of vector to be created containing data with this format: 
l3
[[1]]
[1] v1 v2 v3 v4

[[2]]
[1] w1 w2 w3 w4

[[3]]
[1] z1 z2 z3 z4

But what I got was like this: Seems like it keep repeating elements redundantly in a list. 
print(l3)

[[1]]
 [1] 100.00000  99.45692  98.91680  98.37960 101.04577 100.49701  99.95124  99.06635  98.52834  97.99326 100.14615  99.60228  99.06137

[[2]]
 [1] 100.00000  99.45692  98.91680  98.37960 101.04577 100.49701  99.95124  99.06635  98.52834  97.99326 100.14615  99.60228  99.06137
[14]  99.99692  99.45386  98.91375  99.15577  98.61728  98.08171  98.73635  98.20013  97.66683  99.45615  98.91603  98.37884

[[3]]
 [1] 100.00000  99.45692  98.91680  98.37960 101.04577 100.49701  99.95124  99.06635  98.52834  97.99326 100.14615  99.60228  99.06137
[14]  99.99692  99.45386  98.91375  99.15577  98.61728  98.08171  98.73635  98.20013  97.66683  99.45615  98.91603  98.37884 100.71692
[27] 100.16995  99.62595  96.63577  96.11096  95.58901  98.29635  97.76252  97.23160  98.53615  98.00103  97.46881

I have no idea how to make it work. Anyone to reply or comment is always appreciated.

```
     ml<-list(c(-0.00543076923076923, 0.0104576923076923, -0.00933653846153846, 
                  0.00146153846153846), 
                c(-3.07692307692302e-05, -0.00844230769230769, -0.0126365384615385, 
                  -0.00543846153846154), 
                c(0.00716923076923077, -0.0336423076923077, -0.0170365384615385, 
                 -0.0146384615384615))

       f2<-function(x) x+1
       l2<-lapply(ml,f2)
       l2

       l3 <- vector("list", 3)
       g<-c(100)

       for(i in 1:3){
           for(j in 1:4){
              k=2
              while(k<= 4){

                g<- c(g, (g[k-1]*l2[[i]][j]))
                l3[[i]]<- g 
                k<-k+1
            }

          }

      }
```

print(l3)

Comment: It's not clear to me what your code is trying to accomplish. Can you give an example of what `l2` vs `l3` are supposed to appear as? Why did you choose `1:3` for `i` and `1:4` for `j` and starting at `k=2`? I don't understand the intent of your code and that makes it hard to figure out where your expected behavior is diverging from the observed behavior.

Comment: l2 is just to convert the values of ml to compute g index for 3 different vectors in the ml. l3 should generate the g index for each case within each vector in the ml. g index is computed by: g(t)=g(t-1)*(1+excess return(t)). excess return refer to ml list here. The first value in each output vector (of list)  should start with  g1=100. g is an index to compare relative returns of portfolio depending on different weight of investment in 2 assest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ml<-list(c(-0.00543076923076923, 0.0104576923076923, -0.00933653846153846, 
       0.00146153846153846), 
     c(-3.07692307692302e-05, -0.00844230769230769, -0.0126365384615385, 
       -0.00543846153846154), 
     c(0.00716923076923077, -0.0336423076923077, -0.0170365384615385, 
       -0.0146384615384615))

f2<-function(x) x+1
l2<-lapply(ml,f2)
l2

l3 <- vector("list", 3)
g<-c(100)

m<-1
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:4){
    g[j+1] <- g[j]*l2[[i]][j]
  }
  l3[[i]] <- g

}
```

That´s the following result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 100.00000  99.45692 100.49701  99.55872  99.70423

[[2]]
[1] 100.00000  99.99692  99.15272  97.89977  97.36735

[[3]]
[1] 100.00000 100.71692  97.32857  95.67043  94.26996
```

Comment: Thanks for your code .But when running it, I had the following errors:

Comment: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In l3[[i]][j] <- g[(m - 4):(m - 1)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In l3[[i]][j] <- g[(m - 4):(m - 1)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In l3[[i]][j] <- g[(m - 4):(m - 1)] :

Comment: The function should compute: g1=100, g(t)= g(t-1) * (1+excess return(t)), t=time (1,...T) for each weight. Here, ml is et  for 3 different weight of investment.

Comment: The output should be like: [[1]]
[1] 100.00000  99.456923 100.49701  99.5558719, 99.704228

Comment: [[2]]
[1]  100, ..., ..., ..., ...

Comment: [[3]]
[1]  100, ..., ..., ..., ...

Comment: Gonna work on it

Comment: Just updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks Filipe! Could you check your code again?  It only gave me the outcome of the last vector. Also, the results for two vectors are correct, but the last vector [[3]] should be like this: 100, 0.716923, -0.02412, 0.000411, -6E-06

Comment: Oh, I got it wrong. Your solution was all correct. My calculation for the 3rd vector was wrong. Thanks a lot Filipe !!!